# Get a single item from mongoDB using Mongoose and express.js, return custom page on Null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get an object from mongodb database using Express.  I can get the object when it exists, however when it doesn't I want to send a text/custom page or do anything in fact, but the app keeps crashing.

I tried several codes and they all did not redirect me to but just crashed and sent me to a random page saying `<the path> 404 This page could not be found. Page Developed by @yandeu`.

```
app.get("/item/:id",(req,res)=>{
    Item.findById(req.params.id).then((item)=>{
        if(item){
            res.json(item)
        }else{
            res.sendStatus(404) 
            // and also these lines
            //item = {"Status":"not Found"}
            // res.json(item) 
            //and also this line
            //res.send("404 page")
            //res.sendFile(__dirname+"/404.html")

        }
    }).catch(err =>{ 
        if(err){
            throw err
        }
    })
})
```

After that I deleted everything and kept the `findById` function and I think (not sure) that it throws, that's why the app crashes. I put the whole thing in a `try` and `catch` and the same problem happens.

```
app.get("/item/:id",(req,res)=>{
    try{
        Item.findById(req.params.id).then((item)=>{            
        res.json(item)
        })
    }
    catch(err){
        if(err){
            throw err
        }
        console.log("not found")
    }
})
```

Comment: _"Page Developed by @yandeu"_... sounds like you're using somebody else's code / library. Please [edit] your question to contain a [mcve]. It's also not clear what you mean by _"did not redirect me"_. There is no redirect code in your question. Finally, what do you mean by _"crashing"_? Does the server process stop? If so, there would typically be some sort of error message reported in the terminal where you're running it

Comment: @Phil i'm not using anyone else's code, this is literally what literally the function I have, I stated exactly what my problem is and everything i tried, I mentioned all the functions i tried in my code comments, by crashing i mean crashing i mean it stops working, you either can help or not, no need to be rude about it

Answer (score 0):

The mongoose [`Model.findById()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findById()) method is an asynchronous task. That means you need to wait for it to be settled before you can use it's return value.

> I am new to express and JS in general

I appreciate that to a beginner in JavaScript, handling asynchronous code can be confusing. It is typically done in two ways. Either with [Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing#callbacks) or using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises).

Mongoose used to support callbacks but has now moved to promises. That means you need to use either `then().catch()` blocks or the preferred `async/await` pattern with `try/catch` blocks.

In your answer you have correctly identified a solution using `then().catch()` blocks but having nested `then()` blocks can lead to readability and maintainability problems similar to those encountered when using callbacks.

Here is an example using `async/await`:

```js
app.get("/item/:id", async (req, res) => { //< Marks the callback as async
   try{
      const item = await Item.findById(req.params.id); //< Use of await keyword
      if(!item){ //< item will be null if no matches in database
         return res.status(400).json({ //< Early return if no match
            message: 'No Item found'
         })
      }     
      return res.status(200).json({
         item: item
      });
   } catch(err){
      console.log(err); //< Log the actual error so you can check
      return res.status(500).json({
         message: 'Error on server'
      });
      //or whatever response you want to send
   }
});
```

You will find that all of the database queries in mongoose are asynchronous so you will need to remember this.

Comment: i tried if(!item) and it still throws an error, i dont think findbyid returns a null when the item isnt found and i dont know why, also when you said "having nested then() blocks can lead to readability and maintainability problems" do you mean in the future when adding maintaining the code?

Comment: The `findById` returns the document or `null`. If it throws an error then that's where you need to start debugging. The `catch` block in the answer will catch that error and log the error to the console.  Check your terminal to see what it says. `findById` is a pretty simple method so it will likely be a `Cast to ObjectId failed` error where you haven't passed a proper value as the `_id` parameter. By that I mean something is wrong with `req.params.id`. @ahmad

Answer (score -1):

my intution was correct findById() throws an error and crashes the app when the object does not exist, I just wasn't familar with handelling errors in JS. Anyways here is the correct code if anyone needs it in the future

```
app.get("/item/:id",(req,res)=>{
   Item.findById(req.params.id).then((item)=>{
        res.json(item)
    }).catch(err =>{
        if(err){
            res.sendFile(__dirname+"/404.html")
            //or whatever response you want to send
        }
    })
})
```